# Postgresql: Looping through a date_trunc generated group

Tags: postgresql

I've got some records on my database that have a 'createdAt' timestamp.

What I'm trying to get out of postgresql is those records grouped by 'createdAt'

So far I've got this query:

`SELECT date_trunc('day', "updatedAt") FROM goal GROUP BY 1`

Which gives me:

`+---+------------+-------------+
| date_trunc                   |
+---+------------+-------------+
| Sep 20 00:00:00              |
+---+------------+-------------+`

Which are the days where the records got created.

My question is: Is there any way to generate something like:

`| Sep 20 00:00:00                         |
| id | name        | gender | state | age |
|----|-------------|--------|-------|-----|
| 1  | John Kenedy | male   | NY    | 32  |
|                                         |
| Sep 24 00:00:00                         |
|                                         |
| id | name        | gender | state | age |
|----|-------------|--------|-------|-----|
| 1  | John Kenedy | male   | NY    | 32  |
| 2  | John De     | male   | NY    | 32  |`

That means group by date_trunc and select all the columns of those rows?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please try `SELECT date_trunc('day', "updatedAt"), name, gender, state, age FROM goal GROUP BY 1,2,3 `. It will not provide as the structure, you expect, but will "group by date_trunc and select all the columns ".

Comment: Just tried it and it works! Thanks a lot! Is there any way to make it look like the structure I described above or is that something postres just does not do.

Comment: You won't get that structure in a simple and single query. This is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `SELECT date_trunc('day', "updatedAt"), name, gender, state, age FROM goal GROUP BY 1,2,3`. It will not provide as the structure, you expect, but will "group by date_trunc and select all the columns ".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you point me to where should I look for to get something like the structure I described?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? You can loop through the distinct date and get the set of data you require.

Comment: NodeJS and yes that is what I was thinking, was just wondering if there was a way of doing something like that via postgres.